# How to correctly save html content in MYSQL table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, encode

How to correctly save HTML content in the MYSQL table using PHP. I used the following functions of PHP but no luck.

```
$encodedHTML = htmlspecialchars($cs_htmlEditor);
$encodedHTML = urlencode($cs_htmlEditor);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? Is there any error message given? Is this the whole code - cause it does not use a database in any way

Comment: Have you tried `htmlentities()`?

Comment: html code is not saving as it is...

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari no i didn't

Comment: @Upasana  try it, and before putting the fetched data to your inner html, try  `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: I depends on what you are storing.. if you simply need to store html content then y not simply grab the content as text and dump in column of type `text`? (obviously you need to filter the input before!)

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by users. It should show how the HTML is saved "incorrectly". How do you know it is saved "incorrectly"? Maybe the way how you display the HTML code is incorrect, but we cannot tell without the source codes you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **base64_encode** and **base64_decode**, your column data type should be BLOB.

To encode data in base64

```
$encodedHTML = base64_encode($cs_htmlEditor);
```

To retrieve the data

```
$decodedHTML = base64_decode($cs_htmlEditor)
```

Comment: I don't think  this is a good way, as It's just HTML codes that is to be encoded.Using base64_encode()  is not good for that purpose, moreover it will cost 33% more space than the original data size.

Comment: I just want to save the HTML content in the database and then put that in innerHTML

Comment: please share your html content and data type of the column

Comment: i used base64_encode and changed the type to BLOB... but still i am not getting HTML content

Comment: Please share more details..what is your HTML content ?